# Postgres: How to get json array of multiple boolean columns?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

PG_VERSION: 9.2

I have got a table with multiple boolean flags.

Eg:

```
id,flag1,flag2,flag3
```

Problem is, I want to get json array of these flags with its count like:

```
[{"title":"flag1","count":2},{"title":"flag2","count":3},{"title":"flag3","count":0}]
```

How to achieve this result? Tried this

```
    create or REPLACE function count_test(OUT json_string text) returns text
LANGUAGE plpgsql    AS $$
BEGIN    SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(rows))into json_string FROM ( select sum(case when flag1 then 1 else 0 end) as flag1,
sum(case when flag2 then 1 else 0 end) as flag2,
sum(case when flag3 then 1 else 0 end) as flag3 FROM flags
) rows;
  END;
$$;
```

but with this I can only get 
`[{"flag1":2,"flag2":2,"flag3":0}]`

Awaiting immediate response.

Comment: instead of case I'd rather cast `flag1::int`?.. so `sum(flag1::int) ` looks more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could aggregate `row_to_json` results to array and then try casting it to json and so on, but considering the very limited json support in 9.2 I'd just build json from string, eg:

```
postgres=# with flags(id,flag1,flag2) as (values(1,true,true),(2,false,true))
, s as (select sum(flag1::int) as f1, sum(flag1::int) as f2 from flags)
select concat('[{"title":"flag1","count":',f1,'},{"title":"flag2","count":',f2,'}]')::json from s;
                          concat
-----------------------------------------------------------
 [{"title":"flag1","count":1},{"title":"flag2","count":1}]
(1 row)
```